# PHPSpec - testing with AbstractSpec

Tags: php, tdd, phpspec

Don't find this solution, as more people try testing abstract classes. This is not what i want.

I have patter strategy, and all classes should implements interface.
Wanted to add base spec, that rest should extends and add own things.

I should repeat my code in all specs?

Now, I have 2 in to strategies specs:

```
function it_should_implements_LoadStrategyInterface()
{
    $this->shouldBeAnInstanceOf(LoadStrategyInterface::class);
}
```

How to not repeat myself?

I try to do `AbstractStrategy`, but got

> `Class 'spec\LoadStrategy\Strategies\AbstractStrategy' not found`

I'm missing something? Or code like this, is not autoloaded? Or maybe, this is bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should repeat it in every spec. A workaround is to make your Spec file extending another Spec file (where you have this common example) that itself extends the base phpspec class. I would go with explicit describe (testing) this constraint in every concrete class by the way.

Comment: The after 5 classes with one interface, you would have 5 copies of that. Any test about that interface, you would copy too. And you accept, in any change in interface, you will have to change 5 specs and 5 classes. No have no problem with that? DRY?

Comment: @timiTao you're just testing that an interface is implemented. A think it's not a big deal and, as code is also documentation, in this case I prefer to have this explicit. Btw, as suggested, you can write a superclass and extend from it in every spec file.